# CSS: how to make the left edge of a div follow the right edge of a sidebar with animated width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, border, sidebar

Being just an occasional HTML/CSS/JavaScript coder, I’m stuck with a seemingly simple problem.

I want to build a very simple website layout with a content div and a sidebar on the left that can be hidden. The content div has a variable width; the right side always sticks to the right side of the browser window, the left side adjusts to the sidebar. If the sidebar is displayed, it should use a defined proportional part of the browser window width.

```js
function toggleSidebar() {
  var sidebar = document.getElementById("mySidebar");
  var content = document.getElementById("myContent");
  if (sidebar.style.width === "0%") {
    sidebar.style.width = "25%";
    content.style.marginLeft = "25%";
  } else {
    sidebar.style.width = "0%";
    content.style.marginLeft = "0%";
  }
}
```

```css
#myHeaderBar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 90px;
  z-index: 1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #A2A2A2;
}

#mySidebar {
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  position: fixed;
  top: 98px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 25%;
  bottom: 0px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border-right: 1px solid #A2A2A2;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#myContent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 98px;
  margin-left: 25%;
  bottom: 0px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Sidebar Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="myHeaderBar">
    <h2>Header</h2>
    <a href="#" onclick="toggleSidebar()">Toggle Sidebar</a>
  </div>

  <div id="mySidebar">
    <p>Some Link</p>
    <p>Some Link</p>
    <p>Some Link</p>
    <p>Some Link</p>
    <p>Some Link</p>
    <p>Some Link</p>
    <p>Some Link</p>
    <p>Some Link</p>
  </div>

  <div id="myContent">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
      et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
      et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
      et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
      et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

This is all trivial and works just fine.

My problem arises when I try to limit the minimal and maximal width of the sidebar (which is what I want to do).

Of course, I can add

```
max-width:200px;
min-width:120px;
```

to **#mySidebar** and (if displaying the sidebar)

```
sidebar.style.minWidth = "120px";
```

or (if hiding the sidebar)

```
sidebar.style.minWidth = "0px";
```

to **toggleSidebar()**.

But there are no equivalent parameters for the **#myContent** div, i.e. there is no such thing as **min-margin-left** and **max-margin-left**. As a result, text overlaps or gaps in the edge cases:

```js
function toggleSidebar() {
  var sidebar = document.getElementById("mySidebar");
  var content = document.getElementById("myContent");
  if (sidebar.style.width === "0%") {
    sidebar.style.width = "25%";
    sidebar.style.minWidth = "120px";
    content.style.marginLeft = "25%";
  } else {
    sidebar.style.width = "0%";
    sidebar.style.minWidth = "0px";
    content.style.marginLeft = "0%";
  }
}
```

```css
#myHeaderBar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 90px;
  z-index: 1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #A2A2A2;
}

#mySidebar {
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  position: fixed;
  top: 98px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 25%;
  max-width:200px;
  min-width:120px;
  bottom: 0px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border-right: 1px solid #A2A2A2;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#myContent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 98px;
  margin-left: 25%;
  bottom: 0px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Sidebar Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="myHeaderBar">
    <h2>Header</h2>
    <a href="#" onclick="toggleSidebar()">Toggle Sidebar</a>
  </div>

  <div id="mySidebar">
    <p>Some Link</p>
    <p>Some Link</p>
    <p>Some Link</p>
    <p>Some Link</p>
    <p>Some Link</p>
    <p>Some Link</p>
    <p>Some Link</p>
    <p>Some Link</p>
  </div>

  <div id="myContent">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
      et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
      et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
      et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
      et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Is there a concise CSS/JavaScript solution for this problem? I do **not** want to use any Javascript library just because of that.

Thank you in advance for any tips!

Comment: Have a look at CSS-Grid. It can do what you want without any Javascript at all.

Comment: Is all that positioning necessary?

Comment: @Holli: I failed to get the desired result with all CSS grid variants I could think of. How can I set a grid column width to 25%, limit both its min and max values and animate it from 25% to 0% and vice-versa all at the same time while making sure that the neighbour grid will folow suit? If you are sure my issue could be solved this way, please elaborate.

Comment: @Paulie_D: As far as I can see it is to achieve what I want, but in any case, it’s not the cause of my problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your input!

While (unsuccessfully) investigating the CSS Grid solution suggested by @Holli, I found a CSS Flexbox solution that *almost* works (see remaining issue below). Here’s the code snippet; I changed the min and max width of **#mySidebar** to **120px** and **200px** to make the effect more immediately obvious.

```js
function toggleSidebar() {
  var sidebar = document.getElementById("mySidebar");
  var content = document.getElementById("myContent");
  if (sidebar.style.width === "0%") {
    sidebar.style.width = "25%";
    sidebar.style.minWidth = "120px";
  } else {
    sidebar.style.width = "0%";
    sidebar.style.minWidth = "0px";
  }
}
```

```css
#myHeaderBar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 90px;
  z-index: 1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #A2A2A2;
}

#myContainer {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  top: 99px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px
}

#mySidebar {
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  width: 25%;
  max-width: 200px;
  min-width: 120px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border-right: 1px solid #A2A2A2;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#myContent {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="myHeaderBar">
  <h2>Header</h2>
  <a href="#" onclick="toggleSidebar()">Toggle Sidebar</a>
</div>

<div id="myContainer">
  <div id="mySidebar">
    <p>Some Link</p>
    <p>Some Link</p>
    <p>Some Link</p>
    <p>Some Link</p>
    <p>Some Link</p>
    <p>Some Link</p>
    <p>Some Link</p>
    <p>Some Link</p>
  </div>

  <div id="myContent">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
      et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
      et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
      et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
      et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

One issue remains: (EDIT: One issue was solved and the code updated accordingly, so only one issue (not two) remains)

For this to work as it should, I need to position **#myContainer** (the Flex container) **99px** from the top although the height of **#myHeaderBar** is only **90px**. I have no idea why that is. Of course, specifying 99px solves the issue and poses no problem (as far as I can see for now), but I’d like to unterstand what’s happening. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if I understand your problem: Where does the text overlap or gap? You could add an 'inner div' and give it the properties you want so that 
width of myContent - min-width of innerDiv is something like "min-margin" of myContent.

```js
function toggleSidebar() {
  var sidebar = document.getElementById("mySidebar");
  var content = document.getElementById("myContent");
  if (sidebar.style.width === "0%") {
    sidebar.style.width = "25%";
    content.style.marginLeft = "25%";
  } else {
    sidebar.style.width = "0%";
    content.style.marginLeft = "0%";
  }
}
```

```css
#myHeaderBar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 90px;
  z-index: 1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #A2A2A2;
}

#mySidebar {
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  position: fixed;
  top: 98px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 25%;
  bottom: 0px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border-right: 1px solid #A2A2A2;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#myContent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 98px;
  margin-left: 25%;
  bottom: 0px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transition: 0.5s;
  text-align: justify;
  hyphens: auto;
}

#innerDiv {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Sidebar Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="myHeaderBar">
    <h2>Header</h2>
    <a href="#" onclick="toggleSidebar()">Toggle Sidebar</a>
  </div>

  <div id="mySidebar">
    <p>Some Link</p>
    <p>Some Link</p>
    <p>Some Link</p>
    <p>Some Link</p>
    <p>Some Link</p>
    <p>Some Link</p>
    <p>Some Link</p>
    <p>Some Link</p>
  </div>

  <div id="myContent">
  <div id="innerDiv">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
      et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
      et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
      et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
      et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div></div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The text overlaps if 25% equals less than the min sidebar width (75px in my example). In this case, the left border of #mySidebar sticks at 75px, whereas the left edge of #myContent moves farther to the left, eg. 50px. Thus, the text overlaps. – It’s the other way round when 25% equals more than the max sidebar width (400px in my example). Then, the left border of #mySidebar sticks at 400px, whereas the left edge of #myContent moves farther to the right, eg. 500px. Thus, there’s a gap between sidebar and content. I should have shown my example code WITH these min/max values to make it obvious.

Comment: So unfortunately, your suggestion is no solution.

Comment: I edited my original question and added example code WITH these min/max values (I chose 120px and 200px) which hopefully makes the issue obvious.